# Change a links HREF destination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a problem with animating.

My webpage is animated with buttons that have animated opacity on links.
But when my opacity is 0, the links still work so if you click on them you still get send to another page.

I want it to be unclickable until it is visible.

HTML :

```
<a id="click1" href="#" class="btn_header">WELCOME</a>
```

Triggers this

```
<div id="1">
<a href="3dsmax.html"><img class="tile" src="#"></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#click1").click(function () {
  if ($("#1").css("opacity")=="0") {
    $("#1").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1250);
  } else {
    $("#1").animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500);
  }
```

***EDIT: I want the buttons to start invisible(not working) and turn visible(working)
My guess would be to make the HREF:# and when you click the button to make it visible to whatever.html***

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein) and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout) that show/hide the element at the end of the animation

```
$("#click1").click(function () {
    var target = $('#1');

    if (target.is(':visible')){
       target.fadeOut(500);
    } else {
       target.fadeIn(1250);
    }
});
```

**Demo of code** (*including the starting invisible*) http://jsfiddle.net/Ps6Vj/

---

If the duration was the same you could also use the simpler [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle)

```
$("#click1").click(function () {
    $('#1').fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: The problem with .fadeOut() is that it removes the element at the end of the animation.

Comment: @Gaby Hmm, I am busy working with this, but I want it to start invisible and then when you click the links becomes visible.

Comment: @ChrisHolstein , you could make the element be `display:none` with CSS or run `$('#1').hide()` at the start of your script. Added a demo link in my answer

Comment: @JaredGotte, indeed it makes the element inaccessible at the end by setting the display to none (*it does not really remove it from DOM*) but that is what the OP want in my understanding..

Answer (score 0):

`fadeIn/fadeOut` seems to accomplish what you are after, but if you want to use `animate` then you can tap into the callback parameter to hide the link. Just remember to undo everything when you bring it back.

```
  if ($("#1").css("opacity")=="0") {
     $("#1").show().animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1250);
  } else {
     $("#1").animate(
         {"opacity":"0"}, 
         500, 
         function() { 
             $(this).css("display", "none") 
         });
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3bJNq/

Comment: Thank you, this made it work. I had to much trouble working with the fade options because I am a n00b when it comes to Jquery.

Comment: This isn't best because it removes your link.  That means that the elements after it will try to fill that space in.  If you want to maintain the existing structure, use my answer instead.

Comment: It does not remove the element [nor does fadeOut, btw]. The element is still fully accessible once hidden. Both set the `display: none`. If you wanted to leave the element's box you would use `visibility: hidden`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

[JSBin link here](http://jsbin.com/umaZUDO/2/edit?html,js,output)

First of all, don't begin an ID with a number (#1 is bad - use at least #a1).

HTML:

```
<a id="click1" href="#" class="btn_header">WELCOME</a>
<div id="a1" style='opacity: 0'>
  <a href="3dsmax.html">link</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#click1").click(function () {
  if ($("#a1").css("opacity")=="0") {
    $("#a1").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1250);
  } else {
    $("#a1").animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500);
  }
});

$('#a1').click(function () {
  if ($(this).css('opacity')=='0') return false;
});
```